# How to back up VPS to local machine every month automatically

Tags: 16.04, server, backup, vps

I have a VPS Server with Ubuntu 16.04 Server from vultr.com.

I want to back up its content to my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04), this task has to be repeted every month automatically (database and project files).

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you go about backing up a remote Ubuntu VPS via SSH?](/q/166142) and [How to remotely backup a MySQL database?](/q/308106/175814) combined with [How to set a cron job to run a shell script?](/q/350861/175814)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/896350/how-to-vps-server-backup-local-machine-every-month-automaticallyubuntu/896351#896351).

> Depending where you want to back them up, a very simple approach could be:
>
> 1. `mysqldump` the database (it can be done while running)
> 2. Use `rsnapshot` to keep your project's directory in sync with the remote location.
>
> Have you considered using a version control tool like `git` for the
>   project? I'm assuming is a standard web development set-up.
>
> Put all of the above in a script and put it in your `crontab`.